# Vue.js filter objects from api

Tags: vuejs2

Vue.js i need help with this (https://zdravdevadm.tour-shop.ru/api/v1/objects/) i need to filter hotels from that api by star ratings. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Check the rules for a good post - you should at least show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is unclear, we can't give what you want exactly.
Share the code and show what you did upto now.
This is a demo for you how to get data and store them and display.
Since you need to filter. you computed properties.

```
<div id="app">

  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="hotel in hotels" :key="hotel.id">
        {{hotel.name}} {{hotel.starRating}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  </div>  
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created() {
    //here you got your hotels by api

    this.$http
      .get(`hotels`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("Get response is >>>>>>>>>>>>", response);
        const data = response.data;
        for (let key in data) {
          //here you assign those to an array

          this.hotels.push(data[key]);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error is>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", error);
      });
  },

  data() {
    return {
      hotels: []
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter hotels with stars greater than 4:

```
this.$http
.get(API_URL)
.then(response => {
    const filteredData = response.data.hotels.filter(r => r.star >= 4);       
})
```